# Can't upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 (Package dependencies cannot be resolved)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dependencies

This is what I get each time I try to upgrade:

```
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty: Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1 is to be installed
                            Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                            Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is to be installed
xserver-xorg-lts-trusty: Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty (>= 2:1.11) but 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2~precise1 is to be installed"
```

How can I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`apt-get upgrade`

you can try:

`apt-get dist-upgrade`

but I would recommend to do fresh install anyway. Upgrade process is a real troublemaker, and installation process is short and simple. Just don't forget to make a backup of your files.